# Compare dates in a dataframe column with a single date

Tags: r, date, apply, lapply, sapply

I'm trying to compare each date (find maximum value/latest date) for each row in a data frame column with a single date.
For example:

```
   date
1  2018-07-31
2  2018-08-01
3  2018-08-02
4  2018-08-03
```

When I compare to `compare_date="2018-08-02"`, it should give an output of the latest date between each row and the compare_date. So the new data frame would look like this:

```
   new_date
1  2018-08-02
2  2018-08-02
3  2018-08-02
4  2018-08-03
```

I'm trying to use sapply to this problem:

```
data$new_date <- sapply(data$date,function(x){max(x,compare_date)})
```

But I got the output not in a date format, like this:

```
   date        new_date
1  2018-07-31  17745
2  2018-08-01  17745
3  2018-08-02  17745
4  2018-08-03  17746
```

Please Note that I had converted the data$date and compare_date to Date format using as.Date.

Why is the output not in a date format? Am I using sapply in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are vectorised functions available in R to do this instead of using `sapply`. In this case, you can use `pmax` -

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
compare_date=as.Date("2018-08-02")
df$date <- pmax(df$date, compare_date)
df

#        date
#1 2018-08-02
#2 2018-08-02
#3 2018-08-02
#4 2018-08-03
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", 
"2018-08-03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sapply returns that way. You may find out the reason using `as.vector`

```
as.vector(data$date)
[1] 17743 17744 17745 17746
```

Using `Reduce` and `lapply` will helps

```
data$new_date <- Reduce(c,lapply(data$date,function(x){max(x,as.Date("2018-08-02"))}))
data

        date   new_date
1 2018-07-31 2018-08-02
2 2018-08-01 2018-08-02
3 2018-08-02 2018-08-02
4 2018-08-03 2018-08-03
```